# Neo4j Cypher get direct and indirect dependencies/relationships of a service

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have the following use case where I would like to get a graph and table of all direct and indirect dependencies of a specific service.

For example.

`(a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b), (c)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(b), (d)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(c)`

The output I am looking for is a graph starting with service a and showing something like

`(a)->(b)<-(c)<-(d)`

I tried the following cypher query but it does not seem to return the expected results

`MATCH p=(a)-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-() RETURN p`

Any ideas on how I can achieve the above outcome and also limit the depth of indirect relationships?

Comment: The query looks OK to me. Do you need the output to be formatted differently than what you are getting? This documentation explains how to control the depth. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength

Comment: Can you explain in what way the results of your query are not the expected results?